# Alternate background color every 2 rows

Tags: .net, vb.net

I want to alternate the background color every 2 rows.

Example:

[image]

What I get:

[image: Alternate]

I use this code but it doesn't work correctly, as you can see in the image above.

```
Dim contador As Integer
'Adding DataRow
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dataCasados.Rows
    If contador Mod 2 = 0 Then
        pdfTable.DefaultCell.BackgroundColor = Color.RED
    Else
        pdfTable.DefaultCell.BackgroundColor = Color.BLUE
    End If

    For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In row.Cells
        pdfTable.AddCell(cell.Value.ToString())
    Next

    contador += 1

Next
```

Any help pls?

Comment: You need to consider the logic first and then write the code to implement the logic, rather than just plucking the code out of the air without knowing what it has to do. There's nothing difficult here. It's basic arithmetic. If you can can change something every one row then you can change something every two rows because the logic is exactly the same with a jaw-droppingly simple bit of arithmetic added in.

Comment: What transformation do you think you would have to apply to the sequence {0,1,2,3,4,...} to get the sequence {0,0,1,1,2,...}? You already know what to do with that second sequence because you're already doing it. Don't use a sequence that you generate yourself. Use the indexes of the rows, i.e. use a `For` loop rather than a `For Each` loop. Each time you apply your transformation to the loop counter and then do exactly the same thing as you're doing now with the result. It doesn't take any programming experience to apply logic so any beginner can solve at least the logic part of the problem.

Comment: Look, there are a lot of ways to do this, but if you need help with the business logic take time to reflect on this: you  can store the background color you're currently using in a variable. You can change the color you're stocking in the variable every 2 rows using a modulo kinda like you were already doing.

Comment: `If contador Mod 4 < 2 Then` should do it.

Comment: Yes it works great! Thanks dude @AndrewMorton

Answer (score 0):

You should use the DataGridView [RowPrePaint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowprepaint) or [RowPostPaint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowpostpaint) events to change the background color of a Row. Using the event, you don't need to loop the entire `Rows` collection each time something changes in the grid: just the rows that need to be repainted are affected.

Here, the Colors are added to **`rowColors`** array, but you can define these values in custom properties.
The same for the Step/Interval, here assigned to the **`rowStep`** field:

```
Private rowColors As Color() = {Color.Yellow, Color.LightGreen}
Private rowStep As Integer = 2 ' or 1 or 3 or...

Private Sub dataCasados_RowPostPaint(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewRowPostPaintEventArgs)
    Dim dgv = DirectCast(sender, DataGridView)
    Dim colorIndex As Integer = If((e.RowIndex / rowStep) Mod 2 = 0, 0, 1)
    dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = rowColors(colorIndex)
End Sub
```

As an external loop, since it's apparently needed:

```
Dim dgv = dataCasados
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgv.Rows
    Dim colorIndex As Integer = If((row.Index / rowStep) Mod 2 = 0, 0, 1)
    dgv.Rows(row.Index).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = rowColors(colorIndex)
Next
```

Comment: Im using ITextSharp thats why i cannot use that method you post there i need to do it with the two for loops i posted in the question

Comment: I don't know why you cannot use this with ITextSharp (which, BTW1, you should upgrade to [IText7](https://www.nuget.org/packages/itext7/)), but you can use the same logic in a loop. It's the same thing. BTW2, you didn't mention ITextSharp anywhere in your question.

Comment: See the edit (you shouldn't need this, though). Add to your question the information related to the requirements of ITextSharp in this context.